# How to make a pairplot have a diagonal histogram with a hue using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pairplot

I'm trying to make a pairplot of kind scatter plot with histogram diagonals, but when adding a hue the histograms become invalid.

My code before hue:

```py
import seaborn as sn
sn.pairplot(dropped_data)
```

Output:
[image: Output1]

My code after adding hue:

```py
sn.pairplot(dropped_data, hue='damage rating')
```

Output:
[image: Output 2]

What I have tried:

```py
sn.pairplot(dropped_data, hue='damage rating', diag_kind='hist', kind='scatter')
```

Output:
[image: Output 3]

As you can see, when using a hue, the diagonal histogram it goes all weird and becomes incorrect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the hue column is continuous and contains only unique values. As the diagonal is build up of `kdeplot`s, those won't work when each kde is build from only one value.

One way to tackle this, is using stacked `histplot`s. This might be slow when a lot of data is involved.

Another approach is to make the hue column discrete, e.g. by rounding them.

## A reproducible example

First, let's try to recreate the problem with easily reproducible data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20220226)
df = pd.DataFrame({f'Sensor {i}': np.random.randn(100) for i in range(1, 4)})
df['damage'] = np.random.rand(100)

sns.pairplot(df, hue="damage")
```

[image: sns.pairplot using continuous hue]

## Working with a stacked histogram

```py
sns.pairplot(df, hue="damage", diag_kind='hist', diag_kws={'multiple': 'stack'})
```

[image: sns.pairplot with stacked histplot]

## Making the hue column discrete via rounding:

```
df['damage'] = (df['damage'] * 5).round() / 5  # round to multiples of 0.2
sns.pairplot(df, hue="damage")
```

[image: sns.pairplot with rounded hue values]

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question here is "how to have a hue mapping for the scatterplot but not the diagonal when the hue variable is numeric". If so:

```py
mpg = sns.load_dataset("mpg")
sns.pairplot(mpg, hue="cylinders", diag_kws=dict(hue=None, color=".2"))
```

[image]